# Cannot run rails server with Rapid Rails Themes gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Willing to go fast on the front-end and only work thoroughly on the back end, I am willing to use a theme from http://gems.rapidrailsthemes.com/.

When I want to launch my local server through rails s, I am notified that my yarn packages are out of date. I then launch yarn install, and receive the following error message:

```
➜  casimodo_app git:(master) ✗ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.5 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options


========================================
  Your Yarn packages are out of date!
  Please run `yarn install` to update.
========================================


To disable this check, please add `config.webpacker.check_yarn_integrity = false`
to your Rails development config file (config/environments/development.rb).


yarn check v1.12.1
error Couldn't find an integrity file
error Found 1 errors.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/check for documentation about this command.


Exiting
➜  casimodo_app git:(master) ✗ yarn install
yarn install v1.12.1
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error upath@1.0.4: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=4 <=9". Got "11.0.0"
error Found incompatible module
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Anyone could help about this one?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Have a nice day,

Max

Comment: Hello, it's a nodejs issue (not ruby/ror), you have an old dependencies `upath@1.0.4` which is execpt nodejs version between 4 and 9 but you have nodejs 11.0.0. (rails throw an error because it check integrity of node_modules), can you share package.json for more help ?

Comment: Change your installed version of node from v11 to v9, for example using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), then retry.

Comment: Thanks I found the solution!